# Does the 'or' operator or the equality operator have higher precedence in Python?

Tags: python, operator-precedence

Every precedence table I look at for Python states the equality(==) operator is evaluated before the 'or' keyword. Why then is '1' printed for this code? I thought the expression would evaluate as false, and the if block wouldn't run.

```
number = 1
if number == 0 or 1:
    print(number)
```

How about the following code? Why isn't 'False' printed? Instead, the integer 1 is printed. It confuses me how the variable 'a' gets assigned as 1 instead of as a False boolean value.

```
number = 1
a = (number == 0 or 1)
print(a)
```

Comment: Right, `==` *is* evaluated first.  So `1 == 0 or 1` -> `(1 == 0) or 1` -> `False or 1` -> `1`.

Comment: Why do you expect `if number == 0 or 1:` to not be true? `or` means only one of the conditions needs to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are correct. `==` does evaluate before `or`. In the case of `if number == 1 or 1`, what happens is that python evaluates numbers that aren't 0 as `True`. So the first "argument" (`number == 1`) will evaluate to `False`, while `1` will evaluate to `True`. And `False or True` will always be `True`.

The other case (`a = (number == 0 or 1)`) is a little more tricky. In the case of having an assignment of a variable to multiple expressions chained with `or`, Python will assign the variable to the first expression that evaluates to `True` and if it doesn't find any, it will assign to the last expression.

In this case, the first expression (`number == 0`) is `False` while `1` on the other hand is `True`. `a` therefore gets assigned the value of the second expression, which is `1`.

Comment: Do strings act the same way as numbers in a context like this? Would an empty string evaluate to a false value and a string with content evaluate to a true value?

Comment: Yes they would.

Answer (score 0):

```
number = 1
if number == 0 or 1:
    print(number)
```

In above **if** statement, you have two conditions. It always tries to find the boolean expression of the given conditions and block will get executed only when it finds **True**.

```
number == 0
```

First condition evaluates False since the number is 1

```
boolean(1)
```

Second condition evaluates True which is why block of code executed and 1 is printed.

Same happened with the other part of your code.

```
number = 1
a = (number == 0 or 1)
print(a)
```

Just remember that our code tries to find the **True** values. Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

See python docs [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=comparison%20operator#boolean-operations)

> The expression x or y first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Going by your example:

```py
number = 1
if number == 0 or 1:
    print(number)

# disected
print(number == 0) # prints False
print(False or 1)  # prints 1 as it is a truthy value
```

In your boolean operation the equality operator `==` is evaluated before the `or` keyword.
As `number == 0` evaluates to `False` the right side of the `or` operator gets evaluated. `1` is a true statement so `1` gets returned.

But what if both sides evaluate to `False` or have a falsy value?

```py
number = 1
if number == 0 or 0: 
    print(number)     # won't print
```

As `number == 0` evaluates to `False`, 0 is evaluated. That is a falsy value, so the `or` operation returns `False`, or in this case the falsy value `0` which evaluates to False in the `if` statement.